# Why did my Azure virtual machine reboot amid omsagent/omi activity?

Tags: security, azure, rhel8, oms

A virtual machine of mine, running RHEL8 in Azure, was down for a couple minutes. Turns out it rebooted. Telemetry and logs show no issue. There were no dnf updates and no scheduled update window. [Azure service health](https://portal.azure.com/#view/Microsoft_Azure_Health/AzureHealthBrowseBlade/%7E/healthHistory) has nothing to say. Nothing in the [official troubleshooting docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/virtual-machines/understand-vm-reboot) applies. So why did the virtual machine reboot?

I'm not 100 % sure of the sequence of events, but the only hints point towards an Azure-initiated reboot. The activity log on the Azure portal reports an "health event", which is the reboot itself, marked resolved less than 10 seconds later.

```
    "submissionTimestamp": "2024-01-24T05:14:50.701Z",
    "properties": {
        "title": "Reboot initiated from inside the machine",
        "details": "The Virtual Machine is undergoing a reboot as requested by a restart action triggered by an authorized user or process from within the Virtual Machine. No other action is required at this time.",
        "currentHealthStatus": "Unavailable",
        "previousHealthStatus": "Unavailable",
        "type": "Downtime",
        "cause": "UserInitiated"
    },
```

The VM booted a couple seconds after that event was marked resolved:

```
[Wed Jan 24 05:15:01 2024] Linux version 4.18.0-513.11.1.el8_9.x86_64 (mockbuild@x86-64-02.build.eng.rdu2.redhat.com) (gcc version 8.5.0 20210514 (Red Hat 8.5.0-20) (GCC)) #1 SMP Thu Dec 7 03:06:13 EST 2023
```

About 20 seconds *later*, the logs show OMI/omsagent using sudo:

```
Jan 24 07:15:19 <redacted> sudo[39861]: omsagent : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/opt/microsoft/omsconfig/Scripts/3.x ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/opt/microsoft/omsconfig/Scripts/OMSYumUpdates.sh
```

The audit log (`ausearch --format text -if /var/log/audit/audit.log`) shows a flurry of activity from omsagent in the minute before and after, with lines like:

```
At 05:10:17 01/24/2024 system, acting as omsagent, successfully was-authorized omsagent using /usr/bin/sudo
At 05:10:17 01/24/2024 system, acting as omsagent, successfully ran-command /opt/microsoft/omsconfig/Scripts/OMSAuditdPlugin.sh get /var/opt/microsoft/omsagent/87230cd3-6635-446c-bfc0-00e4fd6f2a13/tmp using /usr/bin/sudo
At 05:14:25 01/24/2024 system, acting as root, successfully started-service omsagent-87230cd3-6635-446c-bfc0-00e4fd6f2a13 using /usr/lib/systemd/systemd
At 05:14:25 01/24/2024 system, acting as root, successfully stopped-service omsagent-87230cd3-6635-446c-bfc0-00e4fd6f2a13 using /usr/lib/systemd/systemd
At 05:15:13 01/24/2024 system, acting as root, successfully started-service omsagent-87230cd3-6635-446c-bfc0-00e4fd6f2a13 using /usr/lib/systemd/systemd
At 05:15:16 01/24/2024 system, acting as omsagent, successfully was-authorized omsagent using /usr/bin/sudo
At 05:15:16 01/24/2024 system, acting as omsagent, successfully ran-command /opt/microsoft/omsconfig/Scripts/OMSYumUpdates.sh using /usr/bin/sudo

At 05:10:17 01/24/2024 system, acting as omsagent, successfully was-authorized omsagent using /usr/bin/sudo
At 05:10:17 01/24/2024 system, acting as omsagent, successfully ran-command /opt/microsoft/omsconfig/Scripts/OMSAuditdPlugin.sh get /var/opt/microsoft/omsagent/87230cd3-6635-446c-bfc0-00e4fd6f2a13/tmp using /usr/bin/sudo
At 05:10:17 01/24/2024 system, acting as root, successfully changed-login-id-to root 
At 05:10:17 01/24/2024 root successfully triggered-unknown-audit-rule using /usr/lib/systemd/systemd
At 05:10:17 01/24/2024 root successfully started-session ? using /usr/lib/systemd/systemd
At 05:10:17 01/24/2024 system, acting as root, successfully started-service user@0 using /usr/lib/systemd/systemd
At 05:14:24 01/24/2024 system, acting as root, successfully negotiated-crypto-key SHA256:<redacted> using /usr/sbin/sshd
At 05:14:24 01/24/2024 system, acting as root, successfully started-service libstoragemgmt using /usr/lib/systemd/systemd
At 05:14:24 01/24/2024 system, acting as root, successfully stopped-service libstoragemgmt using /usr/lib/systemd/systemd
At 05:14:24 01/24/2024 system, acting as root, successfully started-service waagent using /usr/lib/systemd/systemd
At 05:14:24 01/24/2024 system, acting as root, successfully stopped-service waagent using /usr/lib/systemd/systemd
At 05:14:24 01/24/2024 root successfully changed-auditd-configuration using signal
At 05:14:25 01/24/2024  unloaded-bpf-program 118
At 05:14:25 01/24/2024 system, acting as root, successfully started-service dracut-shutdown using /usr/lib/systemd/systemd
At 05:14:25 01/24/2024 system, acting as root, successfully stopped-service dracut-shutdown using /usr/lib/systemd/systemd
At 05:14:25 01/24/2024  unloaded-bpf-program 15 
At 05:14:25 01/24/2024 system, acting as root, successfully started-service omsagent-87230cd3-6635-446c-bfc0-00e4fd6f2a13 using /usr/lib/systemd/systemd
At 05:14:25 01/24/2024 system, acting as root, successfully stopped-service omsagent-87230cd3-6635-446c-bfc0-00e4fd6f2a13 using /usr/lib/systemd/system
At 05:14:25 01/24/2024 system, acting as root, successfully started-service gcd using /usr/lib/systemd/systemd
At 05:14:25 01/24/2024 system, acting as root, successfully stopped-service gcd using /usr/lib/systemd/systemd
At 05:14:26 01/24/2024 system, acting as root, successfully started-service mdatp using /usr/lib/systemd/systemd
At 05:14:26 01/24/2024 system, acting as root, successfully stopped-service mdatp using /usr/lib/systemd/systemd
```

Comment: I suspect the only answer is "there's no good reason but that's just what omsagent/omi does every now and then, so if you don't like it don't use Azure nor Microsoft Defender" (not a choice I have), but I'd be happy to be wrong...

Comment: Sounds like a case for Microsoft support. Omsagent is a general management agent in Azure so could be anything. Do the vm activity logs provide any info?

Comment: @Turdie No, there's no information beyond what I said. Azure Support doesn't  typically answer this sort of question, even on the premium plan.